# this.router is undefined while trying router.navigate

Tags: angular

I don't get it why I get router undefined while trying a imperative navigation(if i write on the url, localhost:4200/alunos/1/edit it works fine). The error occurs when i call the editarContato method to navigate to a students detail page this is my detail class >

```
          export class AlunoDetalheComponent implements OnInit {
          router: Router;
          aluno: any;
          inscricao: Subscription;
          constructor(
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private alunosService: AlunosService
          ) { }

          ngOnInit() {
            this.inscricao = this.route.params.subscribe(
              (params: any) => {
                let id = params['id'];

                this.aluno = this.alunosService.getAlunoById(id);
              }
            )};

            editarContato(){
              console.log(this.aluno.id)
              this.router.navigate(['/alunos',this.aluno.id,'editar']);
            }
            ngOnDestroy(){
              this.inscricao.unsubscribe();
            }
        }
```

Here is where I set my Paths

```
  const alunosRoutes = [
         { path: 'alunos' , component: AlunosComponent, children:              [

            { path: 'novo' , component: AlunoFormComponent},
            { path: ':id' , component: AlunoDetalheComponent},   
            { path: ':id/editar' , component: AlunoFormComponent},   

        ]}
    ];
    @NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(alunosRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]

    }
    )
    export class AlunosRoutingModule{

    }
```

I printed aluno.id inside the method editarConsole as u can see, and it prints just fine... Also if I write on my browser localhost:4200/alunos/1/editar, it works.

Comment: Why do you think it should be defined? Is there anywhere in the code where you initialize this field?

Comment: Yes i have a button that calls the method , <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn"
 (click) ="editarContato()">Editar</button>

Comment: That doesn't answer the questions I asked.

Comment: When i hit the button i get the error "this router is undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add route inside the constructor, otherwise its not initialized

```
constructor(
            private router: Router,
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private alunosService: AlunosService
          )
```

and then,

```
 this.router.navigate(['/alunos',this.aluno.id,'editar']);
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan that was actually the problem, my bad for not seeing it, in other pages i had the router inside constructor, not sure why i didnt have it this time

Comment: I am puzzled as well @JBNizet, apparently, if I put these as constructor arguments, those are bound with class properties. It is strange.

Comment: @Harshal The edit added the necessary `private` keyword to make it a field in addition to a simple argument.

Comment: Mine is inside the constructor declared as ``private router: Router`` and i get the same error. (I am using Angular 6)

Answer (score 3):

If your'e getting this error while you have an instance of the router in your constructor, you can try using an arrow function to get the instance. e.g:

```
myFunction = (param) => {
    // this.router...
}
```

Comment: Solved for me, but why?

Answer (score 1):

You should write the router in the constructor with `private` or `public`, then it will be initialized automatically.