# Angular 6 - ERROR TypeError: "this.router is undefined"

Tags: angular, angular6

Well, here i go again with more Angular problems. Sorry (?)

The thing is that i'm trying to redirect the user after a registration but for some reason, i'm getting the next error everytime:

```
ERROR TypeError: "this.router is undefined"
```

Basically, i'm handling the form submit (which works fine) inputs and posting them to my Laravel API, which takes it, executes the registration and returns a success message. Either way, i can't redirect the user (using Angular Router) using the next piece of code:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.authService.registerUser(this.user).subscribe(
      response => {
        let data = Object.assign(response.alert, this.denyControllConfig);
        this.sweetAlert(data);
      },
      error => {
        let data = {};
        let errors = error.error.errors;
        for (let key in errors) data[key] = errors[key][0];
        // this.sweetAlert(data);
      }
    );
    setTimeout(function () {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
    }, 2000);
  }
```

I have imported the Rourter like this in the top of my file:

```
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
```

And this is my class constructor:

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) { }
```

Is there anything wrong with it ?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744072/this-router-is-undefined-while-trying-router-navigate?rq=1 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: As mentioned in the duplicate, use an arrow function: `setTimeout(() => { ... }`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use arrow functions in your code to be able to use the `this`

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Yes, that was it... Thanks :'/

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is in the following code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  this.router.navigate(['login']);
}, 2000);
```

In this case, since you are using anonymous function, the `this` keyword is the context of the function itself. To fix this, change it to:

```
setTimeout(() => {
   this.router.navigate(['login']);
})
```

The way arrow functions work, will allow `this` to be the class context instead of the function context.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setTimeout` must use an arrow function as the callback to avoid re-binding the context of `this`.