# Encountering a "this is undefined" TypeError when using this.router.navigate for Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement an error handler that redirects the page to an error page upon encountering a status 0 error. However, in the console log, I received an error that "this" is undefined. [image]

(There are some this is undefined questions on the site, but I don't think any are applicable)

To implement the error handler, I have the following code. Without the [`this.router.navigate(['/error']);`] line, everything works fine.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

....

constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient,
          private router: Router) { }

....

private getProducts(searchUrl: string): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<GetResponseProducts>(searchUrl).pipe(
      map(response => response._embedded.products),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}

....

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.status === 0) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error);
      this.router.navigate(['/error']);
    } ...
  }
}
```

The route in question directs to the BackendErrorComponent (app.module.ts)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'error', component: BackendErrorComponent},
  {path: 'checkout', component: CheckoutComponent},
  {path: 'cart-details', component: CartDetailsComponent},
  {path: 'products/:id', component: ProductDetailsComponent},
  {path: 'search/:keyword', component: ProductListComponent},
  {path: 'category/:id', component: ProductListComponent},
  {path: 'category', component: ProductListComponent},
  {path: 'products', component: ProductListComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/products', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/products', pathMatch: 'full'},
];
```

This is the component in question (backend-error.component.ts):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-backend-error',
  templateUrl: './backend-error.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./backend-error.component.css']
})
export class BackendErrorComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
      console.log('backendErrorComponent | ngOnInit...');
  }
}
```

HTML (backend-error.component.html):

```
<div class="main-content"><p>Error</p></div>
```

Comment: I kept looking, and this might have the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52080603/angular-6-error-typeerror-this-router-is-undefined . But while this eliminated the this is undefined error, it's still not redirecting, so I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: Kept looking, and this solved it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245450/angular2-components-this-is-undefined-when-executing-callback-function   This question can be marked as duplicate and deleted.

Comment: The author of that answer appears to prefer the use of 'bind'.
I'm not sure what everyone else does, but I much prefer using an 'arrow method'.